# Return formula if the range is not ""

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I wanted to have formula in G3 =

From range J3:L3 find the first value which value is NOT  ""
so since from range J3:L3 the first non "" value is the one in K3 (the value is "GDNdynamic") so then the G3 will return to value in K3 (surely not J3 or L3 instead, because they have value of ""), which is "GDNdynamic"

I have tried the formula =ArrayFormula(INDEX($J3:$L3,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK($J3:$L3),0)))
in G3

but it only worked if the the cell is literally BLANK, not "" , so that's why it didn't work.

Please help on what would the formula be? 
And to be humbly honest I don't prefer the manual formula one since I will add more and more cell to the right later on.

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: the operator for `does not equal` is <>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in cell `G3`:

```
=INDEX(J3:L3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(J3:L3<>"",),0))
```

You don't have to enter as array!

Also, note: `=ArrayFormula(...` is a google-sheets function.